# Wasn't it 1 engine out at liftoff, then another 5 were lost my the end of max-Q?

Tags: thrust, spacex-super-heavy

Here's a picture.  27 engines running out of 33.

Probably not as bad as you'd think.  Yes there's less thrust, but the other engines will be able to run longer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Space Exploration stack exchange!  As it stands, this "question" doesn't really fit the Q&A style this site is intended for.  Your question encourages answers along the line of "No, I think it was only 3 out at liftoff and the 3 more dropped out at various points in the flight." - which doesn't really help except to suggest someone's opinion.  Additionally, this site expects a minimum level of research before posting; your question could be answered _incredibly_ easily just by you watching the relevant portion of the webcast again.

Comment: Presumably you are asking about the SpaceX test flight on 4/20, but in a few months, no one would be able to figure that out by reading this question.

Comment: "Here's a picture" – No, here isn't.

Answer (score 5):

The engine-loss timeline according to the SpaceX livestream:

- T+15: Three engines (one center, two outer-ring) out sometime prior to the engine-status display showing up.
- T+39: Third engine in the outer ring fails.
- T+61: Fourth engine in the outer ring fails.
- T+68: Clear view of the tail of the rocket, showing six engines out (one center, five outer-ring) despite the status display only showing five out.
- T+79: Max-Q callout
- T+101: Engine status display shows an additional outer-ring engine failure.  This engine was visibly running in the T+68 view.
- T+112: The T+101 engine is shown as operating again.

---

Other videos of the launch suggest even more engines were lost; [Everyday Astronaut's video](https://twitter.com/i/status/1649515491621216258) shows up to 8 engines out at one point.

The energy of a rocket launch goes into three things: 1) fighting the force of gravity, 2) fighting aerodynamic resistance, and 3) getting the rocket up to orbital speed.  With fewer engines operating, more of the energy goes into fighting gravity, leaving less for getting the rocket up to speed.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the recent Starship launch you are talking about then it seems likely that a lot of damage was done just before lift off. The rocket was slow to get off the pad and the concrete below it disintegrated blasting the rocket and everything around with fragments.

https://twitter.com/JerryPikePhoto/status/1649052722698784771